# Sub executed before another

Tags: vb.net

I have the following sub

```
Public Sub Transfer()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim Searching_Date As String
        Dim Name As String
        Dim Presente As Boolean
        Dim Foto_Presente As Boolean


        For i = 0 To CDIi - 1
            Searching_Date = Image_Date(Camera_Day_Images(i))
            Name = Replace(Camera_Day_Images(i), Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\", "")

            Presente = False
            j = 0
            While (Not Presente And j <= PCi)
                If (Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date)) = PC_Directory(j) Then
                    Presente = True
                Else
                    Presente = False
                End If
                j = j + 1
            End While

            If Presente = True Then
                Foto_Presente = False
                k = 0
                List_PC_Day_Images(Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date))
                While (Not Foto_Presente And k <= PDIi)
                    If (Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name) = PC_Day_Images(k) Then
                        Foto_Presente = True
                    Else
                        Foto_Presente = False
                    End If
                    k = k + 1
                End While
                If Foto_Presente = True Then

                Else
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\" & Name, Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name)
                    PC_Day_Images(PDIi) = Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name
                    PDIi = PDIi + 1
                End If

            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date))
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\" & Name, Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name)
            End If
        Next
        Principale.LFine.Text = "Tutte le tue foto sono state trasferite con successo"
        Principale.Button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

It copies any photos from my device to my computer. So if I have a lot of photos It can take several time and I want to notify this. In fact I change the text in the label, than I call the Sub and finally rechange the label.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LFine.Text = "attendere prego..."
        Transfer()
        LFine.Text = "Operazione completata con successo"
    End Sub
```

But the results are that Transfer () starts and just after he finished changing the label.

Why??? How can I fix this problem??
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After `LFine.Text = "attendere prego..."` add this line:

```
LFine.Update()
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call to  `tranfers()` in an `if` statement

Change your `Sub` to a `Function`,

```
Public Function Transfer() As Boolean

...

then 

  If tranfers() = true then 

    LFine.Text = "Operazione completata con successo"
  End if
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your process is a blocking process. The label is "updated" but the form is redrawn only after the whole process ends. Others have suggested to use `Application.DoEvents()` or `LFine.Update`, but the best way to do what you want is to make your process parallel.

You could use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker
```

In the `Load` event of your form...

```
AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_DoWork
AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgw_RunWorkerCompleted
```

And then set your code like this...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LFine.Text = "attendere prego..."
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim Searching_Date As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Presente As Boolean
    Dim Foto_Presente As Boolean


    For i = 0 To CDIi - 1
        Searching_Date = Image_Date(Camera_Day_Images(i))
        Name = Replace(Camera_Day_Images(i), Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\", "")

        Presente = False
        j = 0
        While (Not Presente And j <= PCi)
            If (Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date)) = PC_Directory(j) Then
                Presente = True
            Else
                Presente = False
            End If
            j = j + 1
        End While

        If Presente = True Then
            Foto_Presente = False
            k = 0
            List_PC_Day_Images(Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date))
            While (Not Foto_Presente And k <= PDIi)
                If (Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name) = PC_Day_Images(k) Then
                    Foto_Presente = True
                Else
                    Foto_Presente = False
                End If
                k = k + 1
            End While
            If Foto_Presente = True Then

            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\" & Name, Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name)
                PC_Day_Images(PDIi) = Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name
                PDIi = PDIi + 1
            End If

        Else
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date))
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Camera & Path_in_Camera & "\" & Name, Path & "\" & Right_Date(Searching_Date) & "\" & Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted
    Principale.LFine.Text = "Tutte le tue foto sono state trasferite con successo"
    Principale.Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Just make sure you don't access any control of your form inside `bgw_DoWork` method.

Comment: Thank you much!!, And If I want to do same thing of "LFine.Update()" with a Form?? Terminate the Form_Load before the Sub Transfer()? I prefer do not use the background working.